# django: redirect issue logout functionlaity

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect, logout

I want to redirect user to a specific website `example.com` after `logout`

I have added following code in app's `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [    
  url(r'^logout', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': 'https://www.example.com/'}),
]
```

But I am getting an error `django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

I found a solutions to redirect to any view after logout, but how to redirect to another website?

`django version 1.9`

As per suggestion here is new code added to redirect another website from custom view..

views.py

```
#call for logout
return HttpResponseRedirect('/myapp/logout')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^logout', views.custom_logout, name='logout'),
```

views.py

```
def custom_logout(request):
  request.session.flush()  
  redirect('https://www.example.com/')
```

I am getting error `Reload the page to get source for: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/logout`

Comment: My answer explains how to fix the `NoReverseMatch` error, but it does not help you redirect to another website. Redirecting to another host can be a security risk. The Django [logout view code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L122) specifically prevents `next_url` from being a different host. If you want to logout then redirect to a different website, you'll have to write your own view that does this.

Comment: @Alasdair Ok. Can you please explain me in that case to redirect another website from custom view?

Comment: please check edit in question

Comment: First, I would call `auth_logout(request)` instead of `request.session.flush()`, to keep your view as similar to the [Django view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L122) as possible. Second, you need to return the redirect response: `return redirect(...)`.

Comment: still getting same error.

Comment: I don't understand where 'Reload the page to get source for' is coming from or what is causing it - it sounds like an error from the browser, not the Django app.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `name` to your url pattern.

```
urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'^logout', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='logout'),
]
```

As an aside, using the string `'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'` is deprecated. You should import the view instead. For example, you can do:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'^logout', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

Comment: Now I am getting `302 found` with this error 'Reload the page to get source for: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/logout'

Comment: I have added `return redirect('/myapp/logout')` in view file at some condition.

Comment: I tried server restart using `runserver` command, but not working

Comment: I don't understand your comments. Please update your original question with more details.